# Usage of git checkout FETCH_HEAD -- file

Tags: git, github

Used to get a certain file out of many ones in repo by

```
$ git fetch origin; git checkout FETCH_HEAD -- thefile
```

with that file name overwrite one with its name, now how to get it as another name and untouch `thefile` ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `git show <ref>:<path>` to output file content, then redirect it where you want :

```
git show FETCH_HEAD:thefile > otherpath
```

(See here about the specific [ref:path](https://git-scm.com/docs/revisions#Documentation/revisions.txt-emltrevgtltpathgtemegemHEADREADMEememmasterREADMEem) syntax.)